# How do I calculate the area of different land uses from one shapefile into a different set of polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, area

I'm using ArcMap10.8.2 and was trying to use Tabulate Area but I either didn't use it right or it is the wrong tool for the job.

I've attached an example image. I am trying to get the area of each type of land use (shapefile polygons in orange/green/blue/grey) that is within each of the black zones. The blue/green/orange is all in one shapefile with a 'land_use' field and the grey is in another shapefile but can be combined or split into individual shapefiles if needed.

The end results would be the black polygons with fields like Landuse1_area, Landuse2_Area, etc.

What would be the best tool for this?

[image]

Comment: What didn't work with tabulate area? Did you rasterize your land use polygons? When you read the docs this tool only works on raster data, polygon shapefiles are rasterized *'If the zone dataset is a feature, the cell size is the shorter of the width or height of the extent of the zone feature dataset in the output spatial reference, divided by 250.'* if you do the rasterization of the land use data yourself then that allows you control over the cell size used and origin.

Comment: If all your data is in vector format, sounds like you need to use the Union tool to do all the clever intersection then a simple summary statistics tool on the results grouping by boundary (your black polygon IDs)

Comment: @Hornbydd I pondered the same thing, it wold be more accurate, but it's difficult (and tedious) to get the summary statistics into columns like Tabulate Area... perhaps an edit with Excel (or OpenOffice Calc) followed by Join Field https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000 would meet the requirements.